# Android retrofit SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, retrofit

Как можно записать данные с полученного джейсона в базу данных скльюлайт?

Класс пожо массив значений:

```
public class Example {

    @SerializedName("values")
    @Expose
    private List<Value> values = null;

    public List<Value> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

}
```

Класс пожо значений:

```
public class Value {

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("year")
    @Expose
    private String year;
    @SerializedName("genre")
    @Expose
    private List<String> genre;
    @SerializedName("director")
    @Expose
    private String director;
    @SerializedName("desription")
    @Expose
    private String desription;
    @SerializedName("image")
    @Expose
    private String image;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public List<String> getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public String getDirector() {
        return director;
    }

    public String getDesription() {
        return desription;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }
}
```

Каждый объект нужно внести в базу данных, чтобы можно было взаимодействовать с ними. Спасибо.

Comment: 1 создать таблицу с нужными полями, потом сделать DB insert в нее

Comment: Как вариант, вы можете сохранить в базе данных просто `json` строку, и в дальнейшем работать с ней

Answer (score 0):

возможно, Вам подойдет такой пример работы с Room [sample](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/529-urok-5-room-osnovy.html)

Рекомендуваю Вам озанакомится с [документация](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)